# Get all objects of Additively loaded Scene? (LoadSceneMode.Additive)

Tags: unity, scene, scenemanager

I learned how to Load and unload scenes in unity. using LoadSceneMode.Additive.

I like to spit up my scenes as much as possible and retain the stuff I need as I go along.

I'd like to be able to find all objects loaded from a specific scene. Obviously Unity knows but I can't find how to get them.

For now, my workaround is to put them in a specifically named empty or have them tagged in a certain way, but that is a workaround.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/49077/get-all-items-from-hierarchy.html) mixed with your needs, I would proceed in this way:

```
List<GameObject> FindSceneObjects(string sceneName){
    List<GameObject> objs = new List<GameObject>();
    foreach (GameObject obj in Object.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)))
    {
        if(objs.scene.name.CompareTo(sceneName) == 0){
            objs.Add(objs);
        }
    }
    return objs;
}
```

Or you can compress the for-loop using a linqstatement

```
var objs = from GameObject go in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)) where go.scene.name == sceneName select go;
```

Comment: OP wants to get the objects that belongs to a "specific scene". This code piece returns all GameObjects in the game, regardless of the scene they belong.

Comment: As far as I know the object in a previous scene are deleted when a new scene is loaded. This happen in my project to when I switch from main menù scene to the core scene I have no more the previous objects

Comment: Indeed I Have like 4 or more scenes open at a time; start, Menu, Debug, Background demo and high scores..... I want to be able to hide each of them as I want.

Comment: @Leggy7 Not necessarily, if you specify `LoadSceneMode.Additive` parameter in the loading method, the existing scenes will remain untouched, while the new one gets loaded "_additively_".

Comment: @Leggy7 DontDestroyOnLoad(this) during start or awake; will also preserve objects across loads.  That is how we transfer data across levels most of the time

Comment: Sorry I was not in the new multi scene scenario of unity. I guess I would proceed as I updated my answer. @user2888973

Comment: @Leggy If you correct your code I will accept your answer as it set me on the right track and solved my problem.

Comment: @user2888973 I modified as  per optimizations

Answer (score 1):

Cache all objects at the start and detect the changes in the array (or the list).

To elaborate more, have a list like this:

```
//This list holds all the GameObjects that are currently in the game.
private List<GameObject> _existingObjects = new List<GameObject>();
```

And call this method at the beginning of the game, and every time a scene is loaded:

```
//using System.Linq;

public List<GameObject> FindNewGameObjects()
{
    //Get all GameObjects.
    var allObjects = (FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject[]).ToList();

    //Substract the existing GameObjects from all GameObjects, so the result will be the new ones.
    var result = allObjects.Except(_existingObjects).ToList();

    //Update our list.
    _existingObjects = allObjects;

    //Return the result.
    return result;
}
```

The return of the `FindNewGameObjects()` method will be the list of GameObjects that came with the loaded scene.

***Note:*** The code is not tested.

Comment: I see your point... Make a list of object loaded from scene one..... make a list of objects from scene one and 2 and delete those from scene one. Load scene 3 and delete the ones from scene 1 and 2 ..... etc.... is there no other way?

Comment: @user2888973 Yes, you got it right. This is the quickest way I am aware of to solve this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Unity has a struct named `Scene`. From `Scene` you can get all of the root `GameObjects` of this particular scene.

> Note that the code is not tested.

```cs
public static class SceneExtensions
{
    public static void GetAllGameObjects(this Scene scene, out List<GameObject> allGameObjects)
    {
        GameObject[] rootGameObjects = scene.GetRootGameObjects();

        allGameObjects = new List<GameObject>(rootGameObjects);

        for (int a = 0; a < rootGameObjects.Length; a++)
        {
            //? This is kind of a hack because you can use recursive or other methods to access children via `Transform - GetChild()`. I haven't tested which method is more efficient.
            Transform[] childrenTransform = rootGameObjects[a].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

            for (int b = 0; b < childrenTransform.Length; b++)
                allGameObjects.Add(childrenTransform[b].gameObject);
        }
    }

    public static GameObject[] GetAllGameObjects(this Scene scene)
    {
        scene.GetAllGameObjects(out List<GameObject> allGameObjects);

        return allGameObjects.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then the usual approach is to get scene by build index.

```cs
Scene scene = SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(sceneBuildIndex);
```

> From my own experience, only loaded scenes will give you the correct result when using this method to get a scene. I couldn't find a way to get a `Scene` of unloaded `SceneAsset` at run-time (I would appreciate if someone shared this with me if such thing is achievable).

Then you can proceed to getting all of the `GameObject`s of that `Scene`.

```cs
GameObject[] sceneGameObjects = scene.GetAllGameObjects();
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem got solved. I will put points toward Leggy7 as he gave me the idea to solve my the problem.

The Old procedure is his way of solving it....

```
List<GameObject> FindSceneObjects_Old(String sceneName)
{
    List<GameObject> objs = new List<GameObject>();
    foreach (GameObject obj in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)))
    {
        if (obj.scene.name == sceneName)
        {
            objs.Add(obj);
        }
    }

    return objs;
}
```

This is my way of solving it using LINQ

```
List<GameObject> FindSceneObjects(String sceneName)
{
    var objs = from GameObject go in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)) where go.scene.name == sceneName select go;

    return objs.ToList();
}
```

**Note: Both codes tested and functional**

I am aware there is a shorthand for writing LINQ statements but since I have a Background in SQL I am used to this format.

Comment: Careful when keeping these result lists though, you might cause unintended memory "leaks".

Comment: Thanks for the reminder; you are right; I forgot garbage collection cannot clean up as long as this list exists. when I unload a Scene. Good call